# JCheckBoxMenuItem cannot be added to Menu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

The src code of **JCheckBoxMenuItem** has the following class head:

```
public class CheckboxMenuItem extends MenuItem implements ItemSelectable, Accessible
```

So when a class extends another one it means that it should also inherit its type. Or not?

My problem is that I can't add the **JCheckBoxMenuItem** to a **JMenu** (it needs a MenuItem to be added).

The following code does not work for me:

```
private void initMenu()
{
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    mnAudio = new JMenu("Audio");
    menuBar.add(mnAudio);

    mnitmQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    mnFile.add(mnitmQuit);


    rmnitmNoice = new CheckboxMenuItem("Noice");
    // Eclipse gives error Message below *
    mnAudio.add(rmnitmNoice);

    rmnitmNuke = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Nuke");
    // Same here
    mnAudio.add(rmnitmNuke);
}
```

> The method add(**JMenuItem**) in the type JMenu is not applicable for the
>   arguments (**CheckboxMenuItem**)

I m quite sure that I used this one before and had no problems with it. But since I started to use **Marven** I get strange behaviour sometimes (other example: @Override does not work for Methods, that implement interfaces anymore)

Anyone with the same issue or the solution?

Comment: Swing component start with a "J". I'm not sure what you are using. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)  for working examples.

Comment: “The src code of JCheckBoxMenuItem has the following class head” No, it doesn’t.  That’s not javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem, it’s java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didnt notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VGR explained in his comment: The mistake was trying to add a CheckboxMenuItem instead of a JCheckBoxMenuItem.